# How to modify a word in XML which has similiar set of Nodes using VBScript

Tags: xml, shell, batch-file, vbscript

Following is an Example XML, 
I need to replace D74DVP1 in all the places. Please help me ? 
I could only able to replace the word only in first Node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Forest>
        <Domain>
            <!-- PartitionType:Application -->
            <Guid>01706323-d9a7-4f8d-90d0-1bfb7c88d1d0</Guid>
            <DNSname>ForestDnsZones.D74DVP1.local</DNSname>
            <NetBiosName></NetBiosName>
            <DcName></DcName>
        </Domain>
        <Domain>
            <!-- PartitionType:Application -->
            <Guid>5aca253d-4f3f-475b-b76e-13cd3c694570</Guid>
            <DNSname>ForestDnsZones.D74DVP1.local</DNSname>
            <NetBiosName></NetBiosName>
            <DcName></DcName>
        </Domain>
        <Domain>
            <!-- ForestRoot -->
            <Guid>87d8593d-fcee-4e75-acb6-67b415f5d4a8</Guid>
            <DNSname>D74DVP1.local</DNSname>
            <NetBiosName>D74DVP1</NetBiosName>
            <DcName></DcName>
        </Domain>
    </Forest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [replacer.bat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)

```
call replacer.bat "C:\Example.xml" "D74DVP1" "SomethingElse"
```

?

Comment: Never seen you post this on DosTips or maybe I just missed it.  Is this just more of a basic find and replace compared to JREPL and FINDREPL?

Comment: @Squashman - Yep , I've never posted this on dostips .It nothing so powerful as JREPL or FINDREPL , but I rarely need all the options they offer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Batch file solution, but it is problematic and slow. You may use a Batch-JScript hybrid script like JREPL.BAT or FindRepl.bat instead, that run *much faster* and have the benefits of regular expressions, but it seems too much just to achieve a simple replace in one file. Fortunately, you may also use the same approach of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368982/how-to-change-specific-string-in-a-project-with-batch/17431173#17431173): write a small Batch-JScript hybrid script specifically developed to solve just this problem. Here it is:

```
@set @a=0  /*
@cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < Example.xml > Example.new
@goto :EOF */

WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(/D74DVP1/g,"SomethingElse"));
```

For further details on what those strange @lines means, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167742/execute-wshshell-command-from-a-batch-script/15176096#15176096). For a detailed explanation of JScript regular expressions, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx).

PS - Perhaps you forgot the "g" (general) option in the regexp of your VBScript (unposted) code?